# Можно ли вставить переменную JS в innerHTML в массив?

Tags: javascript

Скажите, а можно как то написать чтобы вставить переменную peremenka в php массив?
что

```js
var peremenka = 1;
.innerHTML = "Введите сумму от <?=$types[peremenka ]["min_sum"] ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет нельзя, так как к моменту, когда будет доступна переменная `peremenka` на клиенте серверный скрипт уже отработает.

Если же значение статическое - то его можно вставить непосредственно на сервере.